# How to replace all instances of "\/" with "/" in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, replace

So I have a weird link like:

```
https\/\/blahblah.com\/path\/example
```

What I want to do is replace every `"\/"` with just a `"/"`.

When I try

```
re.sub("\/", "/", soup)
```

It doesn't change anything. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The `\ ` here escapes the forward slash. So, either use a raw string, or escape the backslash itself.

Comment: `re.sub(r"\/", "/", soup)`

Comment: Maybe `\\` has special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: you have to escape backslashes

Comment: To add to the previous comments: `"\/"` is actually `"/"`.

Comment: @coldspeed that doesnt change anything

Comment: @JoshKisb How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- Make the Regex pattern raw string so Python does not do any per-interpretation and passes it to `re` as-is
- Escape the `\` with `\`; otherwise just `\/` escapes `/` changing nothing as `/` is not anything needs escaping. So, you are replacing `/` with `/`.

So, use:

```
re.sub(r"\\/", "/", soup)
```

**Example:**

```
In [157]: s
Out[157]: 'https\\/\\/blahblah.com\\/path\\/example'

In [158]: re.sub(r"\\/", "/", s)
Out[158]: 'https//blahblah.com/path/example'

In [159]: s = 'https:\/\/dog.ceo\/api\/img\/labrador\/n02099712_7775.jpg'

In [160]: re.sub(r"\\/", "/", s)
Out[160]: 'https://dog.ceo/api/img/labrador/n02099712_7775.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really tell you why re.sub does not work for your case, although I suspect some problem with the escape character interpretation of "/".

However,

```
s = 'https:\/\/blahblah.com\/path\/example'
s.replace('\/','/')
```

did what you want to do for me I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can split by using split('\') method on the string and then join the list elements in a single string so that the backslashes are replaced

```
''.join(weird_string.split('\\')
```

Answer (score -1):

mystring.replace("/", "\ /") its working for Me